# Would like help and advice on working with codes and buttons on MS-Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on an Excel document where I would like to click on a cell and have a box pop-up with options of more command buttons to choose from. When the user clicks on one of the buttons within the user form the button it would then move a selection of that line of A:G to another sheet. I will have multiple lines and would like to code to adjust to the box where the initial command was initiated from. I have the first button and the user form complete and it is working well. The issue is on the next set of buttons to copy, paste and delete the line. Here is what I have so far. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub FireChief_Click()
Dim i As Long: i = 1
Dim n As Long
Dim nLastRow As Long
Dim lastRow As Integer
With ActiveSheet
    For n = nReference To nLastRow Step 1

ActiveSheet.UsedRange

Set r = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
nLastRow = r.Rows.Count + r.Row + 1
Set Reference = Selection
Next Copy_to_Range()
ActiveWorksheets.Range("Reference").Copy
   Destination = Worksheets("Fire Chief").Range("nLastRow")
Worksheets("Fire Chief").Columns("A:G").AutoFit

End Sub
```

So instead of the code listed above, I tried to rework it with some of the input that was provided. Basically this in a way would work like an Access document, and when the button was clicked it would do all of the work for the end user. I work in a fire dept and would like to make it easier on those who have to use it. There are 10 sheets that I have to work with and once I figure out one I will rewrite to match for the other. The new code is below

```
Option Explicit
Sub BaseFireMarshal_Click()

End Sub

Sub FireChief_Click()
Dim i As Long: i = 1
Dim n As Long
Dim nLastRow As Long
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim B As Integer
Dim R As Range
    Set R = Sheet5.Range("A2:G999")
    If Worksheets("ActiveSheet").Range("A:XFD").Copy_ = True Then
    Dim continue As Boolean
        continue = True
        If continue = True Then

            Worksheets("Sheet5").Activate
            B = Worksheets("Sheet5").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Worksheets("Sheet5").Cells(B + 1, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Worksheets("Fire Chief").Columns("A:G").AutoFit
            Worksheets("Sheet5").Deactivate
        End If

        If Application.CutCopyMode = False Then 
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ActiveSheet").Cells(1, 1).Select
        End If

End Sub



Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't complete understand your question but here are a few pointers that might help improve your existing code: Firstly, Always use `Option Explicit` in your code. Second, you have `nLastRow` variable in quotes in your **Destination**. If you put your variable in `quotes`, it's then treated as string and you don't get the value of the variable. Third, never use `ActiveSheet`. Qualify your sheet. `ActiveSheet` is dangerous because you cannot always be sure if `ActiveSheet` is always the one you expect

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to click on a cell and have a box pop-up with options of more command buttons to choose from.

you could do this with grouping columns, from the "data" tab. essentially it collapses/expands a portion of the worksheet.

> the button it would then move a selection of that line of A:G to another sheet

cut and paste

> would like to code to adjust to the box where the initial command was initiated from

gonna wanna use "selection.column" or "selection.row" in your VBA code for this.

> Here is what I have so far.

as for your code, I never use named ranges. I always use range(cells(row,column),cells(row,column)) because then its dynamic.

Try doing that and get back to us.